# why deselect "Copy to project's folder" when adding the facebook sdk iOS. framework

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to integrate the facebook sdk for ios in my app and I am following this tutorial:

[tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/)
[tutorial_2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)

When adding the framework to my project it says to deselect the "Copy to project file" which is something I always select when adding files.

Why to do that? Will it play if I deselect it when I export and publish my app in the App Store? If I select it what are the cons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Copy to project file" simply means that it will copy all your Facebook classes to your project folder and reference if this class file will be from your project copied files. If you uncheck that option, reference will be from where you dragged that file.

So this will not at all affect while export and publish app to Apple App Store.

Actually you should not select this option as Facebook says as it create multiple copies of Facebook classes which is not required.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: I think it does! I was just confused because everytime I was selecting that and I thought that if you don't that will affect when app is going to be published. This also does not make any difference in the output size, right?

Comment: @P.J If we deselect "Copy items into destination group's folder", then the framework files will not be available in the version control system repository. Also every user cloning the repository will have to install Facebook SDK on their local machine separately. Right?